# Searching for Public and Private documents with roles in Lucene

Tags: lucene, umbraco, lucene.net

I am currently trying to build a search in Lucene (from Umbraco) which searches for public documents and protected documents which can be seen by the user's role only. The issue I am having is that Lucene returns all public items and all protected items, but not by role.

My raw Lucene search is:

```
+nodeTypeAlias:pdfdocument +isProtected:false (+rolesAllowed:"userrole" +isProtected:true)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't really doing what you intend.

`+nodeTypeAlias:pdfdocument` query will return only pdfdocuments.

`+isProtected:false` query will return only public documents

`(+rolesAllowed:"userrole" +isProtected:true)` query will prefer, but not require, documents matching "userrole", which are protected.  However, since the above term prevents any match on a protected document, we shouldn't see this.

Or, to rewrite a bit differently (your query doesn't strictly map to AND/OR syntax):

```
nodeTypeAlias:pdfdocument AND isProtected:false AND OPTIONALLY (rolesAllowed:"userrole" AND isProtected:true)
```

The query I believe you are looking for would be more like:

```
+nodeTypeAlias:pdfdocument +(isProtected:false (+rolesAllowed:"userrole" +isProtected:true))
```

Which could be rewritten, by the way, as:

```
nodeTypeAlias:pdfdocument AND (isProtected:false OR (rolesAllowed:"userrole" AND isProtected:true))
```

This doesn't really explain the behavior you describe though.  If it is returning all docs, both public and protected, I suspect you need to take a look at what is actually stored in the `isProtected` field.  That field must contain `false` in order for it to match the query you listed.  It may contain more than one term, possibly containing both `false` and `true`.